# Want to update my input value with v-model

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to change the value of an hidden input with vue js. I added a v-model to the input and I am trying to update it in a method.

My input looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="payment_method" v-model="payment_method">
```

My vue js:

```
data: function() {
      return {
        name: '',
        payment_method: '',
.
.
.
methods: {
        submitAddPaymentMethod(){
          window.stripe.handleCardSetup(
            this.clientSecret, card, {
                payment_method_data: {
                    //billing_details: { name: cardHolderName.value }
                }
            }
          ).then(function(result) {
              if(result.error) {
                  var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                  errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
              } else {
                  // has no effect on my input
                  this.payment_method = result.setupIntent.payment_method; 
                  this.$refs.form.submit();
              }
          }.bind(this));
```

Maybe someone has an idea how to do this. Would appreciate that!

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add nextick() to wait for the DOM to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a different `this` in the promise callback than the one you're expecting.

Use `fat arrow` to solve this.

```
.then(result => {
   if(result.error) {
     var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
     errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
   } else {
      // has no effect on my input
      this.payment_method = result.setupIntent.payment_method; 
      this.$refs.form.submit();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no success..it only works if I use refs.